# Laravel 7 cors problem for nuxt with grouped prefix

Tags: laravel, cors, nuxt.js

New to nuxt and laravel 7 Route::group

Update opened an issue here:

https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/issues/487

My laravel and cors package versions:

```
- "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
- "laravel/framework": "^7.24",
```

My Api Routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {
    Route::post('signin', 'SignInController');
    Route::get('me', 'MeController');
    Route::post('signout', 'SignOutController');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'snippets', 'namespace' => 'Snippets'], function () {
    Route::post('', 'SnippetController@store');
    Route::get('{snippet:uuid}', 'SnippetController@show');
});
```

The auth route works but the snippet one doesn't work.

My cors is like this:

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'api/snippets', '*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

I also tried this

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

Before every retry, I used the `php artisan config:cache` command.

Cors error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/snippets. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

This request `http://localhost:8000/api/snippets/` works fine in postman but not in nuxt, I get the cors error.

Can someone tell me what is happening here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dd or any log function in laravel will affect the cors.

Here is a quote from the official site https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors#echodie

> Echo/die
> If you echo(), dd(), die(), exit(), dump() etc in your code, you will break the Middleware flow. When an output is sent before headers, CORS cannot be added. When the scripts exits before the CORS middleware finished, CORS headers will not be added. Always return a proper response or throw an Exception.

This code will make it work:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $snippet = $request->user()->snippets()->create();

        return fractal()
            ->item($snippet)
            ->transformWith(new SnippetTransformer)
            ->toArray();
    }
```